# Enabling of I2C-0 via "dtparam=i2c_vc=on" on Pi 3B+ causes "I2C-10" & "I2C-11" to appear and disables GPIO 10 GPIO 11

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, i2c, wiringpi, pi4j

For reference:

- I am using the latest release Pi OS Lite, Aug 2020 version.
- I am developing an application using Pi4J.
- I am referring to pins via this Pinout: [Pin Numbering - Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://pi4j.com/1.2/pins/model-3b-plus-rev1.html)

I am using both I2C buses, 0 and 1, in my application. To enable I2C-0 I added `dtparam=i2c_vc=on` to the `config.txt` file. I am *also* using GPIO 11 (BCM pin 7) as a digital out. This works just fine with the Raspberry Pi Zero W. However, when I changed to a Pi 3 B+ (and bumped up the OS to the next release, but not sure that is the issue), the following occurs:

When I include `dtparam=i2c_vc=on` to the `config.txt` file I get access to the I2C-O bus, as expected. *However*, in addition to `/dev/i2c-0` appearing, I also get `/dev/i2c-10` and `/dev/i2c-11`, and when attempting to provision GPIO-11 in Pi4J, I no longer have access to GPIO-11 (BCM pin 7). My guess is that the mysterious appearance of I2C-11 and disappearance of GPIO-11 are related.  As I was using GPIO-11 for something and I have already fabricated a PCB, this puts me into a bit of a bind.

I would much rather use the 3 B+ and not have to patch the physical hardware. This does not appear to be an issue with Pi4J. My guess/hope is that there is probably a trivial solution with device overlays, but no luck searching for this specific problem. Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a **dtoverlay I²C-gpio software i2c controller on gpio pins**

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states

```
        i2c_vc                  Set to "on" to enable the i2c interface
                                usually reserved for the VideoCore processor
                                (default "off")
```

The 2nd I²C interface is reserved for HATs (and also probably used for GPIO extension - although this is undocumented). It WAS usable on the older Pi, but effectively is unavailable. You can disable probing for HATs but AFAIK not the other services e.g. PWR LED etc).

The difference between the Pi3 and earlier models is easy to explain. The addition of wireless requires more GPIO so an extender was added and some of the on board circuitry e.g. LEDs was moved to the extender.

The Zero models lack the USB hub and Ethernet.

Comment: The thing that is curious is that (only for 3B+, not Zero W), enabling I2C-0 via i2c_vc parameter will also affect other pins (GPIO 10 & 11), creating an I2C-10 and I2C-11 and preventing use of GPIO-10/GPIO-11. I have not found any documentation as to what is going on with that. I understand the HAT part, reserved for EEPROM, etc. Guess thats what happens when you take your chances. I had no issues until I switched from Pi Zero W to Pi 3B+. Thank you for your help.